# Is there any other way to get this done?

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, community

```
function myPicklistChanged(){
        var myPicklistElement = document.getElementById('{!$Component.theForm.thePageBlock.thePageBlockSection.myPicklist}');
        var myPicklistValue = myPicklistElement.options[myPicklistElement.selectedIndex].value;

        if (myPicklistValue == 'Biochemical Repack'){
            document.getElementByClass("Hidecolumn").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementByClass("Hidecolumn1").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementByClass("Hidecolumn2").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementByClass("Hidecolumn3").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("Hidecolumn4").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("Hidecolumn5").style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        else if (myPicklistValue == 'AO Powder'){
            document.getElementById("Hidecolumn").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("Hidecolumn1").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("Hidecolumn2").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("Hidecolumn3").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("Hidecolumn4").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("Hidecolumn5").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
        else if (myPicklistValue == 'AGT™ (Advanced Granulation)'){
            document.getElementById("Hidecolumn").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("Hidecolumn1").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("Hidecolumn2").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("Hidecolumn3").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("Hidecolumn4").style.visibility = "hidden";
            document.getElementById("Hidecolumn5").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
```

In my custom  VF page I have a table and I used this java script code for hide table row. I have more than 40 row and I do not want to use Id = "Hidecolumn,1,2,3,4,5," for every row. Is there any better way that i Can use One ID for all of the raw. I tried using a class `document.getElementByClass("Hidecolumn").style.visibility = "hidden";` but it does not work . Any idea how to do that? Thanks

**VF Page**

```
<apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Product_Format__c}" onchange="myPicklistChanged();" id="myPicklist"/>

<table id="table_section4" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <th>QUANTITY</th>
                    <th>UNIT SIZE FILL VOLUME</th> 
                    <th class="Hidecolumn">LIQUID<br/>PACKAGING</th>
                    <th>POWDER AGT<br/>PACKAGING</th>
                    <th>TOTAL<br/>VOLUME:</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Quantity1_1__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Unit_Size_Fill_Volume1_1__c}"/></td> 
                    <td class="Hidecolumn"><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Liquid_Packaging1_1__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Powder_AGT_Packaging1_1__c}" /></td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Total_Volume1_1__c}"/></td> 
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Quantity1_2__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Unit_Size_Fill_Volume1_2__c}"/></td> 
                    <td class="Hidecolumn"><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Liquid_Packaging1_2__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Powder_AGT_Packaging1_2__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Total_Volume1_2__c}"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Quantity1_3__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Unit_Size_Fill_Volume1_3__c}"/></td> 
                    <td class="Hidecolumn"><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Liquid_Packaging1_3__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Powder_AGT_Packaging1_3__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Total_Volume1_3__c}"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Quantity1_4__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Unit_Size_Fill_Volume1_4__c}"/></td> 
                    <td class="Hidecolumn"><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Liquid_Packaging1_4__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Powder_AGT_Packaging1_4__c}"/></td>
                    <td><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Total_Volume1_4__c}"/></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: As I said in your previous (very similar) question - use jQuery. And use functions.

Comment: Well i am not familiar with j query and I have no idea how to assign if (myPicklistValue == 'Biochemical Repack') in Jquery. Anyway ill try. thanks

Comment: Can you also post your table code as well? Just wondering if you could use standard VF features to control visibility, instead of JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

If you changed the ids to a class name of Hidecolumn, you could do something like this:

```
function myPicklistChanged(){
        var myPicklistElement = document.getElementById('{!$Component.theForm.thePageBlock.thePageBlockSection.myPicklist}');
        var myPicklistValue = myPicklistElement.options[myPicklistElement.selectedIndex].value;

        if (myPicklistValue == 'Biochemical Repack' || myPicklistValue == 'AO Powder' || myPicklistValue == 'AGT™ (Advanced Granulation)'){
            var TheColumns = document.getElementsByClassName("Hidecolumn");
            for (var i = 0; i < TheColumns.length; i++){
                TheColumns[i].style.visibility = "hidden";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. You save my lots of time and 100 of coding line.

Comment: Not a problem, glad to help.

Comment: when are you calling this function? is there an onchange event handler on the picklist? And have they all been given the Hidecolumn class?

Comment: I made the changes, but its doing nothing. In my VF code I put like this
<tr>
 <th class="Hidecolumn">LIQUID PACKAGING</th>
</tr>
 <tr>
  <td><apex:inputField value="{!Produ_Brief__c.Unit_Size_Fill_Volume1_1__c}"/></td> 
   <td class="Hidecolumn"><apex:inputField value="{!Produ_Brief__c.Liquid_Packaging1_1__c}"/></td>
   <td><apex:inputField value="{!Produ_Brief__c.Powder_AGT_Packaging1_1__c}" /></td>
 </tr>
 <tr> <td><apex:inputField value="{!Produ_Brief__c.Unit_Size_Fill_Volume1_2__c}"/></td> 
  <td class="Hidecolumn"><apex:inputField value="{!Product_Brief__c.Liquid_Packaging1_2__c}"/></td>

Comment: I will add the VF section on my above code

Comment: Could you also show the part that has myPicklist please

Comment: Im sorry i just added that. Thanks for the help. I really apprentice it

Comment: Not a problem. You've got it up and running then?

Comment: Nope still not working and could not find whats wrong.

Comment: What do you get if you put in console.log(myPicklistElement); console.log(myPicklistValue); console.log(TheColumns); at the end of the javascript function? Are you actually getting values here?